# Can I upload files to post to Blogger / Blogspot?

Tags: blogger, blog

I write a blog on blogspot.com. I frequently include code snippets in my posts, and while I've got the formatting the way I want it, it's annoying to type them in the input box they provide.

What I'd really like is to be able to edit my posts on my own machine (I'd use Vim, personally) and upload the posts when they're ready.

Is there a way to do this? (Other than copying and pasting or writing my own program using the Blogger API.)

Answer (score 2):

I know there is a web interface for this. I have a Bundle in my TextMate that can send to Blogger, although it's not working at the moment 'cause of some ruby problems.

I'll try to fish out the answer for you :)

**Update**

It seems that you can at least post with e-mail.
[Here](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41452) are the instructions for it.

**Update 2**

There is also the possibility of using Google's own API.

[Here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html#InsertingEntry) are the instructions on how to use the API, if you want to make a script etc for yourself :)